# What risks are there using scripting for admin tasks?

Tags: security, powershell

Beginning PowerShell and looking at the automatic tasks that can be run as Admin.

Are there security risks in automating tasks? How can I resolve these issues? Is there a way to script more security before the task is run?

I have been looking for hours trying to find an answer and nothing has come up for database risks, only for PHP and website issues. But what about the active directory or communicating with the servers? Or just simple things like looking for free disk space? Do those pose a security threat to the network?

Comment: This site is for specific questions about programming problems. You're asking for a vague list of risks that might be possible by scripting, which is far from a specific question. Questions asking for lists of things are off-topic here as "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

The topic of securing an OS is *huge* and really off-topic on SO. I recommend you to get a basic course material like, say, CompTIA Security+ or the like. Learn the basic principles and concepts first, then focus on technology specific issues.

That being said, the most obvious security hole with scripted operations is invalid permissions. Consider that the admin script is in a directory that allows write access to non-admin users. Oops, immediate backdoor. Can you figure out why?

Even read access is dangerous. Maybe the admin script has stored credentials in plain-text or serialized on disk? Oops, another a security hole.

Comment: I know the question may be broad but I needed help and I needed to start somewhere. Even if two people took the time to help, I'm better off then I have been the last two days. Thanks for the suggestions they at least pointed me in a direction to think about, that's all I really wanted. I will look up the book, perhaps that will help clarify things better.